How to reference a property from a subschema in a conditional statement?
Imagine we have a JSON schema where one property of a subschema is mutually exclusive depending on the value of a property of another subschema. When doing the if-else statement, how can I reference the value of the subschema property? Here's how I currently have it:
  "$defs": {
    "interaction": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "user_prompt": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "User prompt that the assistant model receives."
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Type of request in the user prompt. Allowed values: 'get_value', 'get_table', 'verification', 'chat', 'malicious'",
          "enum": ["get_value", "get_table", "verification", "chat", "malicious"]
        },
// ... and follows

The interaction property type is the property I want to reference in here. If type="value then the property from the subschema mock_results_metadata will be only value:
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {     // type property from the interaction subschema
            "const": "get_value"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "mock_results_metadata": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "value": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": ["value"],
            "additionalProperties": false
          }
        }
      },
      "else": {
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "const": "get_table"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "mock_results_metadata": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "no_rows": { "type": "integer" }
              },
              "required": ["no_rows"],
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
          }
        }    
      }
    },
//... and follows

Can someone please tell me how can I reference the type property correctly for this conditional statement? Should be implemented in a different way?
Thank you very much. :)
The actual code shown does not work well and does not detect the mock_results_metadata object to validate it, so the issue I think it has to be on how to reference correctly the value of a property from another subschema.
